# How do I save a matched record as a new one and update user_id, using rails and postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am matching incomplete and complete records using postgresql in rails.  Here's the matching code:

```
QualifyingEvent.where("(class_date = :class_date AND course_id = :course_id) 
                    OR (class_date = :class_date AND sponsor_name = :sponsor_name) 
                    OR (course_id = :course_id AND sponsor_name = :sponsor_name)",
                      class_date: '2001-01-01',
                      course_id: 'A111',
                      sponsor_name: 'ICPAS').first
```

I want to save a duplicate of the matched record with the current_user's user_id.  I'm currently using a convoluted work-around where I set a variable, i.e., abc = match, and then parse the match, i.e., user_id = abc.user_id, so that I can create a new QualifyingEvent with the params, e.g., :class_date, :course_id, :sponsor_name, and :user_id

I tried abc = QualifyingEvent.new and then abc = match and abc.save.  It didn't work.

There must be an easier way?!  Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried abc = QualifyingEvent.new and then abc = match and abc.save.
>   It didn't work.

That would make one object equal to another object whereas what you are really wanting to do is just assign the attributes of one object to another object

```
abc = QualifyingEvent.new
abc.assign_attributes(match.attributes)
```

Then sort out the current_user id to whatever value you want plus set the date/time stamps for created_at, updated_a and the id to nil as Rails and the RDBMS will take care of those values when record is saved.

Also to get around the mass assignment protection you can use the :without_protection => true argument

```
abc.assign_attributes(match.attributes, :without_protection => true)
```

see the docs for more info http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/assign_attributes

Comment: I read the docs and tried the following:

    abc = QualifyingEvent.new
    abc.assign_attributes(- code as above -.attributes)

Which works.  The id is 0, the 'nil' returned by matching two records with different id's. If I then try to re-assign the id and save the record,

    abc.update(:id => 'nextval(qualifying_event_id_seq)')

I get a 'duplicate key value violates unique constraint on abc_pkey', 'DETAIL:  Key (id)=(0) already exists.'  So, how do I save the record with assigned attributes as a new record with an id in the correct sequence.  In my case, it should be id 51?  Thanks.

Comment: @user3763682 created_at, updated_at and id should all be set to nil before saving